# Implementar Botão Voltar em Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows, eventos

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Windows 10 e não tenho ideia de como eu implemento um botão voltar em um Pivot igual é no aplicativo Clima da Microsoft.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]